# Flutter doesnt seem to be working on my new PC

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

I got a new system and I've been trying to set up my AS to run flutter but it's not working. After installing git, downloading the flutter zip file and setting up the user variable path, flutter doctor still doesn't run and just stops at
`Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...`

Tried deleting the cache folder, still didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to

1. delete folder in your flutter SDK path flutter/bin/cache (detail info [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2055#issuecomment-336937998))
2. run flutter doctor -v again will trigger downloading Dart SDK